# ucs and biblatex incompatibility (mathletters and utf-8)

Tags: biblatex, unicode, incompatibility

I have a document that I was writing with UTF-8 chars using TexStudio, MikTex (x64) and pdflatex. All updated and running on Window 7 SP1 x64.

Then I decided to start using biblatex citations and now I have an incompatibility problem.

The error is

> Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'. \begin{document}

And here is the code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % this package seems to conflict
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % the x seems to be a problem
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Library.bib}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{MySection}

    \paragraph{MyParagraph}
    Accènt
    λ lamba
    \cite{some_cit}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is a small example. In my full document I have lots of Greek letters, and some of them are in titles. Putting them all into math formulas would be a problem.
What should I do? to make the 2 live together? Should I use another package for citations?

Comment: The documentation of `biblatex` is clear: it is incompatible with `utf8x`. Just do `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Can you make a real example of what you're using the `mathletters` option to `ucs` for?

Comment: I read somewhere that the utf8x incompatibility was fixed. Maybe I remember wrong, but just writing "utf8" instead of "utf8x" produces the same error. I also have to give up the mathletters, but then I can't paste math symbols anymore. It's clearer to see ∞ than to see $∞$, no?

Comment: No, it isn't. Math symbols should go in math formulas.

Comment: Any easy trick to avoid that? I have math symbols that could easily end up in section titles and need to be text.

Comment: Why? I see no reason.

Comment: Because I need it and because, please, I'm asking you. I posted a small contained example, what I really have is far bigger. And, as you should know, math formulas create problems in titles. That's why they need some symbold I have (as the Greek letters) need to be text.

Comment: I've never had problems with math formulas in titles. What `mathletters` does is defining some symbols with `\ensuremath` around them.

Comment: maths formulas should not create problems in titles (the definitions need to be robust but that applies equally to the text versions)

Comment: So, is there another way to do what mathletters does, or what biblatex does, without subverting my whole document?

Comment: are the greek letters in your document Greek words, if so you don't want mathletters in anycase (which gives you a greek styled as math symbols) you want greek in math to be marked as math using `$` or `\(` and greek in text to use a greek text font.

Comment: They are used as math symbols. Is there no way to just paste UTF-8 symbols and forget about them? BTW if I remove the ucs package, write "utf8" instead of "utf8x" and write `$λ$`, it still complains `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:λ not set up for use with LaTeX. The Greek letter $λ`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can abuse the infrastructure of `ucs`; here's a set of tricks that read the files you need in the `ucs` distribution, but under `utf8` which is compatible with `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input{binhex}
\makeatletter
\def\uc@dclc#1#2#3{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{mathletters}=\z@
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{\hex{#1}}}\x{#3}%
  \fi
}
\input{uni-3.def}
\def\uc@dclc#1#2#3{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{default}=\z@
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{\hex{#1}}}\x{#3}%
  \fi
}
\input{uni-34.def}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title{MyTitle}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\section{MySection about ∞}

Accènt λ lambda ∞ 

$λ$ lambda $∞$ 


\end{document}
```

[image]

A different strategy is using `unicode-math-table.tex`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UnicodeMathSymbol[4]{%
  \ifnum#1>"9F
    \expandafter\DeclareUnicodeCharacter\expandafter{\@gobble#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}%
  \fi
}
\input{unicode-math-table}
\@for\next:={% you're probably using text Greek letters
  alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,%
  iota,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,pi,rho,sigma,tau,%
  upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,Gamma,Delta,Theta,%
  Lambda,Xi,Pi,Sigma,Upsilon,Phi,Psi,Omega}\do{%
    \expandafter\let\csname up\next\expandafter\endcsname\csname\next\endcsname
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{MyTitle}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\section{MySection about ∞}

Accènt
λ lambda ∞ 

$λ$ lambda $∞$ 


\end{document}
```

The entries in `unicode-math-table` are of the form

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0221E}{\infty}{\mathord}{infinity}
```

so we remap this to

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0221E}{\ensuremath{\infty}}
```

(I used `\ensuremath` because you want it, but I'd personally avoid it). For the Greek letters, `\upalpha` and so on are used, so I remap also those commands to the usual ones.

Comment: Wow, this seems to work well. Could you add some comments to your code, or give some more details about how this works? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually not sure I really need the `\ensuremath`. You are right that I would prefer the Greek letters to be text (except when they appear in formulas). Does the second solution account for both the small and upper case (e.g. δ Δ)? Which solution would you consider "cleaner"?

Comment: @Agostino None of them is “clean”.

Comment: Right. Which one is less likely to give problems? For example, I have text subscript and superscript where those Greek letters can appear.

Comment: @Agostino `$a_{λ}$` shouldn't make problem.

Comment: Thanks. And `a\textsubscript{λ}` or `a\textsuperscript{∞}` with `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`?

Comment: @Agostino Why? Use TeX's math features!

Comment: True, it's just that I have some names of concepts that are on the edge between math and nomenclature, network science stuff. I do use math stuff for full formulas.